# Save chart from screen device to png with R function

Tags: r, plot, png

I have a problem with all screen device packages. I would like creating a function that save plot to png file. My first aproximation as such as this:

```
   File <- function(plot){
   library(ggplot2)
    png(filename=paste0(deparse(substitute(plot)), width=800, height=600,units = "px")
    plot
    dev.off()
   }
```

But the script returns a completely black png file. If execute the code manual, the script function.

Are there any method to make it work?

Comment: Are they on the different execution attempts on the same system?

Comment: Why not use `ggsave`?

Comment: @hrbrmstr I tried in Windows 10 with R 3.4.2, Raspbian with R 3.1.1 (Raspberry Pi), Lubuntu with R 3.4.2 and Mac OS X Yosemite with R 3.4.1

Comment: @James Thank you for comment when use ggsave, my function works, but always take the last vision in manual

Comment: @APT22 You can pass a particular ggplot2 plot to it as an argument, check the help file.